# Correct filtering of raw devices which are multipath components out of LVM

Tags: lvm, filter, multipath

I have a HP MSA P2000 FC with dual controllers, dual HP SAN switches and a couple of servers with QLogic "ISP2532-based" 8G dual-port cards.  Everything is connected "each to each" way. The OS is really Proxmox VE connected into a cluster, all those are supported by qla2xxx driver, and every node sees 4 copies of each HP volume. They are combined into multipath-devices, which serve as LVM PVs for virtual machines.

This is quite straighforward way to do things. I also configured multipath in the way where it only maps the devices are specified in /etc/multipath.conf, any other are blacklisted. WIthout this multipath touches and maps local RAIDs through itself, which is not very convenient.

What I need to do now is to disallow system to use raw components as LVM PVs in case it is not mapped. While this is covered in Red Hat manuals ([this one](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/DM_Multipath/multipath_logical_volumes.html) at least) , that manual is not applicable for me as it is.

My PVE nodes boot up from local RAID card, which is seen as /dev/sda. It contains a valid LVM group with pve root volume, local data etc. This means I can not filter out all /dev/sdX. I can enable just /dev/sda and filter out all others, but am also not sure if it will always stay /dev/sda. There is also a possibility that other local devices will appear to host private LVM PVs, and nobody knows which names they will have.

System sees which model the device is (multipath -ll shows "HP,P2000 G3 FC").

The question: is it possible to filter LVM by how the SCSI device is appeared in the system? The ideal generic filter would be something like this: LVM is allowed to see its PVs as usual, except devices that appear through QLogic card, or except devices that originate from HP MSA array, because those could only be multipath components and should only be used when multipath-mapped. How to achieve this?

Comment: What version of LVM are you running? Which distribution? On Fedora and RHEL multipath_component_detection should be set to 1.

Comment: As I said, Proxmox VE is the "distribution". It is based on Debian Jessie (8). "lvm version" shows: LVM version:     2.02.116(2) (2015-01-30), Library version: 1.02.93 (2015-01-30), Driver version:  4.34.0

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. The LVM version is quite ancient here. Still filters should work fine. You are right the /dev/sdX may change. I suggest you just filter out the multipath's legs using `r|/dev/disk/by-path/SOMEPATTERN|`. The rule number one is do not mix accept and reject rules in LVM filters - it does not work well.